# Select other layout in same theme in orchard

Tags: layout, themes, orchardcms

I'm creating a theme for my site in Orchard and I want to use a different layout for my blog post detail page.

I found out I can use a naming convention based on the url. But I want to give the admin that uses the theme the option to select another layout. Not necessarily for the blog post, but at least for pages or projections.

I'm totally stuck in this, how can you provide multiple layouts in a theme?

Thanks in advance.
Willem

Answer (score 0):

I would start here http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/12/14/switching-the-layout-in-orchard-cms.aspx It tells how to set a layout to be a certain one and then you can just create a little dropdown or something where users can select the layout.

Comment: There are also several module on the gallery that let you do that.